# Unable to disable Blazor WASM trimming/linking/tree-shaking

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

Targeting the .NET 6 framework but building with the latest .NET 8 SDK.

I'm using a gRPC serialization library that throws an error when serializing a `KeyValuePair`.

I realized it's working fine on my dev computer (even a Release build), but fails when deploying using `dotnet publish`. When the program works, I get this warning in the browser console when loading the page:

> This application was built with linking (tree shaking) disabled. Published applications will be significantly smaller.

I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/configure-trimmer?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that even mentions `KeyValuePair`. Following the instruction, I've added this portion to my Blazor WASM `.csproj` project file:

```
<PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
```

This does not seem to have any impact except I do see this warning while building:

> Publishing without optimizations. Although it's optional for Blazor, we strongly recommend using `wasm-tools` workload! You can install it by running `dotnet workload install wasm-tools` from the command line.

Unfortunately the previous warning message is missing when opening the page and project still crash on serialization.

I've also tried adding this:

```
<BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebAssemblyEnableLinking>
```

But this seems to be for an older version. Also had no impact

I tried to force the argument via the publish command:

```
dotnet publish Server.sln -c Release -p:PublishTrimmed=false
```

Still no difference.

But if I add

```
<EnableTrimAnalyzer>true</EnableTrimAnalyzer>
```

I do see some additional warnings in the build (objects that are unrelated to the one I'm having a problem with), so that proves the project file does take the properties in account.

I tried to add both properties to the ASP.NET server `.csproj` file too (not the WASM app). I tried to delete all `bin`/`obj` folders. I'm making sure to always refresh my page using a full <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> to clear the cache.

I've found many discussions online about setting `PublishTrimmed` to false fixing their issues. Why doesn't it work for me? It seems Blazor wants to run the optimization process no matter what.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/prepare-libraries-for-trimming?pivots=dotnet-8-0#dynamicdependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my Blazor nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.*`from "6.0.11" to "6.0.26" seems to have fixed my issues preventing me to disable trimming.